# When to use SerializableAttribute and ISerializable?

Tags: c#, serialization

Even if you don't apply `SerializableAttribute` or `ISerializable`, every serializer that I know of does a good job of serializing objects anyway - So when is it a good idea, or a requirement, to use `[Serializable]` or `ISerializable`?

I understand `[Serializable]` and `ISerializable` are available whenever the default serialization behavior is undesired, such as, you want to exclude some public properties, or include some private ones.  Is that the only situation where you need to, or should, use `SerializableAttribute` and `ISerializable`?

Comment: Different serializers use different attributes. `Serializable` is used by BinaryFormatter. It may have some use case in XmlSerializer but I haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to export a instance of object with setting in memory into a file and load again the next time you want to used just with the same settings and values before you saved.

[This Link will explain you much better and is awesome the things you canto with it.](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/serialization.htm)